# Adding class name or id to Table with JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, setattribute

Suppose this code to create a table with **plain** JavaScript using DOM ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkqfLwbx/)):

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

How can I add a class name or an id to its cells?
For example I want to be able to modify cells after their creation, so I want just :

```
table.getElementsByClassName("class").style.font-weight: "bold";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **[HTML DOM setAttribute() Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** to add attributes to an element, like following :

```
var td1 = document.createElement('td');
var td2 = document.createElement('td');

td1.setAttribute('class', 'className');
td2.setAttribute('class', 'className');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ references are not encouraged. Checkout http://www.w3fools.com/ :)

Comment: Thanks @RahulDesai for your intervention.. (Link updated to `https://developer.mozilla.org`)

Answer (score 7):

Do:

```
table.setAttribute("id", "myId");
```

Read up: [MDN `Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Use the same function to set `class`, just like @Zakaria mentioned.

Comment: If you are a bootstrap fan like me, add the [class table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/) with: `table.setAttribute('class','table')`

Comment: this is nice, thanks Timo